# Confusion about program output

Tags: java

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        pop1(1234);     
    }

    public static void pop1(int x){
        System.out.print(x % 10);   
        if ((x / 10) != 0){
            pop1(x/10);
        }   
        System.out.print(x % 10);
    }   
}
```

Output  : 43211234

I dont understand the output.
First past '4321' is ok; but how last part '1234' is generated?

Comment: Have you tried debugging through the code, to see at what point different digits are generated?

Comment: Don't forget to mark the answer that helped you as correct.

Answer (score 0):

The last `System.out.print(x % 10);` --> This line causes the values `1,2,3,4` to be printed. This is the last line of each method call.

While entering `X:4->3->2->1` (now printing starts here)
1 is printed, then stack unwinds (method returns), then 2 prints and so on..

Answer (score 0):

The second print is called when the pop1 function returns from the recursion - that is the reason the other four numbers are printed in reverse order. Remove it and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 0):

The first call to:

```
System.out.print(x % 10);
```

generates the reverse number `4321` while the second call generates the direct order `1234`. So remove on of the lines if you need only direct/reverse order.

So you get a direct order `1234` from the second `print()` call because it's executed after the recursion call i.e. innermost recursion call prints `1` at first place while the outermost call prints `4` at the last place.

Answer (score 0):

To visualize what happen you might amend the code like this

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        pop1(1234);     
    }

    public static void pop1(int x){
        System.out.println("enter: " + x % 10);   
        if ((x / 10) != 0){
            pop1(x/10);
        }   
        System.out.println("leave: " + x % 10);
    }   
}
```

produced output

```
enter: 5
enter: 4
enter: 3
enter: 2
enter: 1
leave: 1
leave: 2
leave: 3
leave: 4
leave: 5
```

combine this output with the answer from @TheLostMind and you will understand how the code is working.